# How to get a1Notations from Row with Findall function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search, full-text-search

So I was referencing this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826834/how-to-get-a1notations-when-findall-function-returning-range-range-range-ran" and I like it and what it does but I need to go a little further and im still a beginner but this is what I have.

```
  var searchTerm = "Changeme"; // Please set this.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set this.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheetName = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var completeSearch = dataSheetName.createTextFinder(searchTerm).findAll();
  for (var i = 0; i < completeSearch.length; i++) {
    var range = completeSearch[i];
    var value = range.getValue();
    var rowValue = dataSheetName.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, dataSheetName.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    Logger.log(value) // Value of the searched range
    Logger.log(rowValue) 
    Logger.log(range.getA1Notation()
    //Logger.log(rowValue) // Values of the row of searched range
  }
}
```

This is enough to get me the row that I am looking for and the Cell of what I am searching for but what I want to do is check a column for what I am searching for and return the row then grab the value of another column in the same row and based off that answer send an email out to someone with the answer.

So Search Column H for the "SearchTerm" If I found it in the row check the cell value in column A, B, and C and if then put the values in another sheet to send them out in an email.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of columns "A" to "C" by searching the value of `searchTerm` at the column "H".

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script 1:

When you want to use TextFinder, how about the following script?

```js
var searchTerm = "Changeme"; // Please set this.
var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set this.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheetName = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var completeSearch = dataSheetName.getRange("H:H").createTextFinder(searchTerm).findAll();
for (var i = 0; i < completeSearch.length; i++) {
  var range = completeSearch[i];
  var rowValue = dataSheetName.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 3).getValues();
  Logger.log(rowValue)
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

I thought that in your situation, at first, when the values are retrieved from the sheet and retrieve the expected values in a loop, the process cost might be a bit low. The sample script is as follows.

```js
var searchTerm = "Changeme"; // Please set this.
var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set this.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheetName = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var values = dataSheetName.getRange("A1:H").getValues();
var res = values.reduce((ar, [a,b,c,,,,,h]) => {
  if (h == searchTerm) ar.push([a, b, c]);
  return ar;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Edit:

From your sample Spreadsheet and your replying comments,

- You want to search the column "H".
- You want to use the values of columns "C,D,E" of the searched row.
- About the values of `recipient, subject, body, options` of `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`, you will put `subject` and `options` as the constant value. `recipient` is from the column "G". `body` is like `Here is the list of your employees that are in the sheet Last Name First Name Location 123 456 Test1 1r3 1t1 Test1`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var searchTerm = "Supervisor1"; // Please set this.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set this.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheetName = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = dataSheetName.getRange("C1:H").getValues();
  var email = "";
  var res = values.reduce((ar, [c,d,e,,g,h]) => {
    if (h == searchTerm) {
      ar.push([c, d, e]);
      email = g;
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (res.length == 0 || !email) return;
  var message = {
    to: email,
    subject: "sample subject",
    body: "Here is the list of your employees that are in the sheet Last Name First Name Location\n\n" + res.map(r => r.join(",")).join("\n"), // Modified
    name: "Test",
    bcc: "testing",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Employee Report")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: How could I then take it and say if these values are a match export the a b c column into a email

Comment: Such as Lets say H3 and H4 match so it will take A3 B3 C3 and A4 B4 C4 export them as them into as an array to an email using the MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `How could I then take it and say if these values are a match export the a b c column into a email` and `uch as Lets say H3 and H4 match so it will take A3 B3 C3 and A4 B4 C4 export them as them into as an array to an email using the MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);`, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Jaden Harrod In order to correctly understand your current issue and your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand them. Because from `Such as Lets say H3 and H4 match so it will take A3 B3 C3 and A4 B4 C4 export them as them into as an array to an email using the MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);`, I cannot understand the values of `recipient, subject, body, options`. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: Of course! I really appreciate you helping! 

So I went ahead and made a mock up sheet with the scriupt and what I want to do with it explained in the script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IXth8zC3AO761B7U4_sTWZCHN5_HdNEb4g1luJH2EFo/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks again

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. About the values of `recipient, subject, body` of `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);`, Can I ask you the sample values you expect? You want to retrieve those values from Spreadsheet? Because from your sample Spreadsheet, I couldn't understand those values. So I cannot still imagine your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: So the recipient should be the supervisor email which would be the "searchTerm"s email in F:F so that would be auto grabbed from "res" F column the rest Subject  And options would be hand written by me because it will be thee same across the board. The only thing that would need to be auto is the body which will be a range of anyone that they have a match with. So anyone that has supervisor in E the script will auto email their supervisor with a list of everyone who belongs to them

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `So the recipient should be the supervisor email which would be the "searchTerm"s email in F:F so that would be auto grabbed the rest Subject Body`, I cannot still understand the values of `recipient, subject, body`. Can you provide the sample values of `recipient, subject, body` when your sample Spreadsheet is used?

Comment: @Jaden Harrod And also, in your question, you say `So Search Column H for the "SearchTerm" If I found it in the row check the cell value in column A, B, and C and if then put the values in another sheet to send them out in an email.`. But in your sample Spreadsheet, the column "H" has no values. So I'm confusing about your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: So I made a change to the sheet to only show three inputs although the real one will have 1000+ The scripts goal is to have the supervisors listed. Then Anyone that has the same supervisor will be documented and at the end a email will be sent to the supervisor giving them a list of all their employees. So the recipient of the email will be the supervisor which their email is listed in column F and the subject will be One in the same across the board for this lets say "Employee report" The body will be an overall list of anyone they are listed as the supervisor for

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the values of `recipient, subject, body`. Can you provide the sample values when your sample Spreadsheet is used? And also, in your question, you say `So Search Column H for the "SearchTerm" If I found it in the row check the cell value in column A, B, and C and if then put the values in another sheet to send them out in an email.`. But in your sample Spreadsheet, the column "H" has no values. So I'm confusing your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: So Row 2 and 4 have the same supervisor so the first script will run and see if they do and then it will send an email to the supervisor saying 
Recipient: Supervisor1@test.com
Subject: Employee Report
Body: 
Here is the list of your employees that are in the sheet
Last Name First Name Location
123 456 Test1
1r3 1t1 Test1
Option Bcc: Testemail123.com (This will be static and not automatic)

Comment: I made edits to the sheet to help understand, I am so sorry.

Comment: Let me know if I can do anything else to make it more clear

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right! Now is there a way to make the date look more organized and not on the same line because it is coming out like this. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gZZgaq71Jl3gZeV6bPbTQVYZlwLq7b3/view?usp=sharing

I would like it to be like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1veNq_b4Y_M9gT7H4XdRiAWKt_5T-fe5T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `Now is there a way to make the date look more organized and not on the same line because it is coming out like this.`, I cannot understand what you want to do. So can I ask you about the detail of it? Unfortunately, from your question and your replying, and your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand it.

Comment: I edited the previous comment

Comment: @Jaden Harrod Thank you for replying. From your replying, I thought that you wanted `Here is the list of your employees that are in the sheet Last Name First Name Location 123 456 Test1 1r3 1t1 Test1`. I couldn't notice that you wanted [this situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1veNq_b4Y_M9gT7H4XdRiAWKt_5T-fe5T/view?usp=sharing). I deeply apologize for this. For your request, I updated the script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: I edited to this body: "Here is the list of your employees that are in the sheet Last Name First Name Location" + "\n\n" + res.map(r => r.join(" ")).join("\n"), and its working now in that format. THANK YOU SO MUCH!